# Защита jar-а

Tags: java

В нэте есть сайты, которые продают свои продукты - jar библиотеки, так некоторые предлагают, например, 30-дневный ознакомительный срок. Вопрос, кто что думает, как  они защищают свой продукт? что мне мешает дезасемблировать их либы (кроме лени и совести)?

Comment: Совесть - недостаточная защита?)
В таком случае могу предложить ещё репутацию и угрозу понести ответственность за нарушение лицензии.

Answer (score 4):

Есть механизм проверки лицензий с онлайн доступом. Например, как это реализовано в маркете Android'а и им подобных маркетах: Амазон, Samsung и проч.

1. Имеется аппликация, которая контролирует приложения (назовем контрОллер) - для примера Android Market
2. Контроллер имеет 2 службы а) Сетевая служба доступа к хранилищу лицензий на удаленном сервере. б) Локальную службу к которой может обратиться установленное приложение с запросом на проверку лицензии
3. При запуске приложения, приложение обращается к локальной службе контрОллера с запросом на проверку лицензии. Контроллер обращаеся к серверу проверяет лицензию и возвращает результат.

Преимуществом такого способа является то, что установленное приложение может не иметь никаких сетевых разрешений, а просто обращается к службе контроллера, который и делает всю работу, также приложению не требуется обфускация, кастомный загрузчик классов и проч. Недостаток также понятен - требуется наличие контроллера. В случае десктопа такое малореализуемо (хотя примеры также есть - все тот же [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/)), ну а в варианте мобильной оси - все работает замечательно, чему и свидетельство успешность всевозможных аппсторов на Android, iPhone и проч.

Программный API к контроллеру Android Маркета известен как LVL (License Verification Library) - [описание здесь](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html)

Comment: А почему не требуется обфуксация? Разве код будет недоступен?

Comment: LVL обходится правкой одного лишь байта, поскольку не является частью OS, а реализуется посредством подключаемой библиотеки.
Прочие аналоги тоже не слишком сложно.

Comment: я про защитить простой джар, а не приложение...

Comment: Ну насчет 1-го байта не уверен, ибо все зависит от искусства прогера пишущего проверку лицензии. И к тому же в случае обхода - не будет обновления, не будет возможности докупить в онлайне доп. функции и проч.

Comment: Заставить проверку лицензии всегда принимать на вход статус LICENSED (0x0) вместо NOT_LICENSED (0x1) - не есть проблема.
Найти это место и подправить его - тоже не проблема.
А вот для защиты от этого, т.е. защиты и/или сокрытия кода проверки - см. мой ответ.
Так что ваш ответ "приложению не требуется обфускация, кастомный загрузчик классов и проч." несколько неверен. Ибо приложение, использующее лишь LVL/аналоги для защиты - не защищено ничуть.

Comment: @falstaf - я уже ответил на это (см. выше). Согласен с одним, с тем, что обфускация не помешает, она собственно и рекомендуется - это еще один эшелон защиты, но не главный.

Answer (score 2):

Обфускация + проверка контрольных сумм/хэшей .class-файлов, хранящихся в jar'е.

Также, как возможный вариант - генерация байткода в рантайме, основываясь на каких-то данных (ключе лицензии, например).

Шифрование байткода с загрузкой посредством своего ClassLoader'а.

Что-то еще тут будет сложно придумать, ибо ява.

Comment: это все понятно, можно ли как то дать доступ на время? т.е. джар на неделю например?)

Comment: Конечно, почему нет.

Answer (score 0):

jar файл это простой архив, который содержит набор class файлов. которые в свою очередь являются набором примитивных инструкцию для JVM. последнее означает что они всегда смогут быть декомпилированы (до тех пор пока спецификации JVM общедоступны). лично мне это напоминает ситуацию с машинными кодами и асемблером.

я не давал бы постороннему сами либы, лучше использовать что-то на подобии EJB, когда у клиента есть только интерфейс, а сам функционал находится в другом месте.

если присутствует проблема performance, - то клиенту нужен локальный сервер (имеет смысл сделать его платформенно зависимым но защищенным) который будет проходить авторизацию на вашем сервере, загружать актуальные версии либ, + выполнять функции application server. понятное дело что содержимое классов/jar файлов должно иметь привязку к текущей дате и клиенту, должно передаватся в зашифрованом виде, и хранится только в памяти.

Answer (score 0):

you can see different products for convert jar to exe, so that you can protect the jar

[Convert Jar To EXE, Executable File](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2011/09/convert-java-jar-file-to-exe)